# JS: Recursively calling a promise function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a node.js application that can create thumbnails for images. To avoid freezing the application while generating thumbnails I decided to use an asynchronous [library](https://github.com/honza/node-thumbnail) for creating thumbnails. However depending on the image multiple thumbnail sizes might be needed.

```
var thumbnailSizes = [100];
if (image.type == 'coolImage') thumbnailSizes.push(500);
generateThumbnails(image.filename, thumbnailSizes).then(function() {
    // Do cool things with the saved thumbnails (This is never reached)
});

function generateThumbnails(filename, thumbnailSizes) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var path = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('\\'));
        console.log('start');
        console.log('length = ' + thumbnailSizes.length);
        thumb({
            prefix: thumbnailSizes[0] + '_';
            source: filename,
            destination: path,
            width: thumbnailSizes[0]
        }).then(function () {
            if (thumbnailSizes.length > 1) {
                console.log('next');
                generateThumbnails(filename, thumbnailSizes.splice(0, 1));
            } else {
                console.log('finished');
                resolve('true');
            }
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log('error');
        });
        console.log('end');
    });
}
```

This code successfully creates the first thumbnail but not the second. This is what my console looks like after the code stops running.

```
> Console Output
start
length = 2
end
next
start
length = 1
end
```

The code calls `generateThumbnails()` for a second time successfully but does not call the thumb function again, skipping to the end and never resolving. How can I make this work?

Comment: Instead of `resolve(generateThumbnails(filename, thumbnailSizes.splice(0, 1)));` try to just return the promise `return generateThumbnails(filename, thumbnailSizes.splice(0, 1))`

Comment: That was actually what I tried before using resolve(). Both give me the same result.

Comment: Also `return thumb({...})` :)

Comment: If I return thumb I get the console input `start > length = 2 > end` and no thumbnails are generated.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: @maljukan `resolve(…)` is the one that *works* inside of the `new Promise` constructor, not `return …`. Of course, the `new Promise` constructor shouldn't be used at all…

Comment: @Bergi yes, i agree 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the need for recursion here.

```
async function generateThumbnails(filename, thumbnailSizes) {
  var path = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('\\'));

  return await Promise.all(thumbnailSizes.map(size => thumb({
    prefix: `${size}_`,
    source: filename,
    destination: path,
    width: size
  })));
}
```

Or if you need to create the thumbnails one by one:

```
async function* generateThumbnails(filename, thumbnailSizes) {
  var path = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('\\'));
  for(const size of thumbnailSizes) {
    yield await thumb({
      prefix: `${size}_`,
      source: filename,
      destination: path,
      width: size
    });
  }
}
```

Which is consumable with a `for await` loop in the calling function:

```
for await(const thumbnail of generateThumbnails(file, sizes) {
  // handle single size
}
```

Also, I wouldn't use `.substring()` to make path manipulation, I'm sure the [Node `path` module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) has a function or seven that can help you reliably extract the interesting part from the path.

Comment: While this generates my thumbnails the way I want, It also freezes the main process while it is creating them. Additionally how should I catch errors inside of `Promise.all`?

Comment: `Promise.all()` will reject on the first promise that rejects, so you can add a `try/catch` block around it (since you're in an async function), and you'll get the first error the failed. You can do some more trickery if you want *all* of the errors. As for blocking the main thread, I'm afraid that's the fault of the `thumb` function, and that there's nothing much you can do here. Consider switching to a library utilizing the new `worker_threads` module to do CPU intensive work without blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are resolving your promise with another promise, which might cause the promise chain to be broken, you can try changing:

`resolve(generateThumbnails(filename, thumbnailSizes.splice(0, 1)));`

for

`return generateThumbnails(filename, thumbnailSizes.splice(0, 1))`

However my suggestion would be (if you are using the latest ES versions) to use async/await then you don't need a recursive call and you code will be more readable:

```
// your function definition
//async () => {

var thumbnailSizes = [100];
if (image.type == 'coolImage') thumbnailSizes.push(500);

for(const size of thumbnailSizes) { // do not use a foreach
 const thumbnail = await generateThumbnail(image.fineName, size);
 // Do more fun stuff with your thumbnail
}

});

function generateThumbnail(filename, size) {
        var path = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('\\'));

        return thumb({
            prefix: size + '_';
            source: filename,
            destination: path,
            width: size
        })
}
```

Comment: I get the error `await is only valid in async function`. I'm not sure if I can use the thumbnail function (https://github.com/honza/node-thumbnail) in the way you suggest.

Comment: Take a look at the first part of the code I wrote, you need to define your function as async: // your function definition
//async () => {

Answer (score 0):

You are only calling `resolve` in the `else` block of your condition in the callback, not in the `if` block. Resolving the promise that the recursive call returns won't have any effect on the promise returned by the outer call. Also you never `reject` the promise in case of an error.

Anyway, you should avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), so that you don't need any `resolve` calls at all but can simply `return` from the `then` callbacks to chain promises:

```
function generateThumbnails(filename, thumbnailSizes) {
    console.log('length = ' + thumbnailSizes.length);
    if (thumbnailSizes.length == 0) {
        console.log('finished');
        return 'true'; // are you sure?
    } else {
        var path = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('\\'));
        return thumb({
//      ^^^^^^
            prefix: thumbnailSizes[0] + '_';
            source: filename,
            destination: path,
            width: thumbnailSizes[0]
        }).then(function () {
            console.log('next');
            return generateThumbnails(filename, thumbnailSizes.slice(1));
//          ^^^^^^
        })
    }
}

…
var thumbnailSizes = [100];
if (image.type == 'coolImage') thumbnailSizes.push(500);
console.log('start');
generateThumbnails(image.filename, thumbnailSizes).then(function() {
    console.log('end');
    // Do cool things with the saved thumbnails (This is never reached)
}, function(err) {
    console.log('error', err);
});
```

Also I fixed your recursion - the base case should be the empty array.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, I'm at a complete loss. This function does not trigger `thumb()` once, and based on the console output it really should be. Also I had `generateThumbnails()` as a Promise because the "cool things with the saved thumbnails" part needs to happen after the thumbnails are created.

Comment: Oops, I had missed to add the second fundamental `return` keyword. Should work now.

Comment: `thumb()` is still never called. There are no errors in the console and no resolution is ever reached. Its as if that function isn't even there.

Comment: So you get the `start` log, the `length = …` log with a size of 1 or more, and then nothing? That surely is weird.

Comment: That is exactly what is happening.

Comment: That would suggest your `thumb` function is broken. It returns a promise, but never resolves it. Did you put a breakpoint (or log statement) at the start of `thumb`? Can you post that code as well, please?

Comment: `thumb` is not my function. It comes from here: https://github.com/honza/node-thumbnail/blob/master/src/thumbnail.js

Comment: Oh, that's some pretty horrible code. It appears to break if you are calling `thumb` multiple times concurrently, as it uses global state. I might suggest using the `jimp` package directly. Also, did you install the error handler on the returned promise? And why are you doing promise recursion at all? node-thumbnail appears to take multiple files, its whole code is about making a queuing solution around `jimp` calls.